# Шаблон функции и перегрузка оператора > в с++

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++, перегрузка-операторов

Нужно создать шаблон функции для подсчета элементов, которые больше за значение `val`. Возникла проблема при перегрузки оператора >. Сравниваем значения age из класса `Istota` и значение `val`(вводится пользователем). Компилятор выдает ошибку

> //Invalid operands to binary expression ('Istota*' and 'float')//

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить эту ошибку?  Ниже оставляю фрагменты кода с классом и шаблоном функции.

```
class Istota: public Forma {
  public:
  float age, x, y;
  int oznaka;

Istota(): oznaka(1){
  age=0;}

    Istota (float age_ , float x1, float y1):Forma(x1,y1), oznaka(1){
  age=age_;
    x=x1;
    y=y1;}
    float getx(){
      return x;}
    
    Istota& setx(float x1){
      x=x1;
      return *this;}
    
      float gety(){
      return y;}
    
  Istota&  sety( float y1){
      y=y1;
      return *this;}
    
    float getage(){
      return age;}
    
    Istota& setage(float age_){
      age=age_;
      return *this;}

    Istota (const Istota &other){
      this->age=other.age;
        this->x=other.x;
        this->y=other.y;}
  
  ~Istota(){}
    
    float val;
    bool operator >(const Istota &other){
        return (other.age>val);}
};

template <class T>
T* count(T a[],float val, int s){
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0;i<s; i++){
        if(a[i]>val){ sum ++;} //Invalid operands to binary expression ('Istota *' and 'float')
    }
    cout<<"Результат:"<<sum<<endl;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Судя по всему, вы вызываете, передавая массив указателей (`Istota*a[]`), да и оператора сравнения с `float` у вас и в самом деле нет.  Кроме того, странно, что в вашем операторе вы сравниваете *разные* поля...

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как тогда  должен выглядеть оператор сравнения в моём случае? Просмотрел множество источников, везде аналогичная реализация.

Comment: Что вы передаете в `count`? Как вы ее вызываете?

Comment: Передаю массив объектов, значение с которым сравниваем и размер массива. Пример:       float val=4;  Istota* a[3];    Istota a1(14, 6, 7);     Istota a2(5, 3, 72);  Istota a3(20, 1, 9);
    a[0]=&a1;   a[1]=&a2;   a[2]=&a3;   count (a, val, 3);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выбросьте  `float val;` из класса - оно вам не нужно.

Оператор перепишите

```
bool operator >(float val) const
{
    return (age > val);
}
```

В функции замените

```
if(a[i]>val){ sum ++;}
```

на

```
if( (*a[i])>val ){ sum ++;}
```

Должно заработать.

Но лучше бы вам функцию поменять... Как-то передавать массив указателей мне кажется не самым красивым...